# Is it a bad idea to implement a timer loop in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, performance

In our game project we did have a timer loop set to fire about 20 times a second (the same as the application framerate). We use this to move some sprites around.
I'm wondering if this could cause problems and we should instead do our updates using an EnterFrame event handler?
I get the impression that having a timer loop run faster than the application framerate is likely to cause problems... is this the case?

As an update, trying to do it on EnterFrame caused very weird problems. Instead of a frame every 75ms, suddenly it jumped to 25ms. Note, it wasn't just our calculation *claimed* the framerate was different, suddenly the animations sped up to a crazy rate.

Comment: are you really making the game using the flex framework or are you just coding it in as3 using flexbuilder?

Comment: The majority of the game is pure AS3, loading a lot of CS3-created SWFs. However we do use MXML for UI, which I think gves the best of both worlds. I should add, we are only getting performance issues when we try to load especially large game levels... normally it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for the Enter frame, in some special cases it can be useful to have two "loops" one for logic and one for the visuals, but for most games I make I stick to the Enter frame-event listener. Having a separate timer for moving your stuff around is a bit unnecessary since having it set to anything except the framerate would make the motion either jerky or just not visible (since the frame is not redrawn).

One thing to consider however is to decouple your logic from the framerate, this is most easily accomplished by using getTimer (available in both as2 and as3) to calculate the time that has expired since the last frame and adjusting the motions or whatever accordingly.

A timer is no more reliable than the enter frame event, flash will try to keep up with whatever rate you've set, but if you're doing heavy processing or complex graphics it will slow down, both timers and framerate.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rundown of how Flash handles framerates and why you saw your content play faster.

At the deepest level, whatever host application that Flash is running in (the browser usually) polls flash at some interval. That interval might be every 10ms in one browser, or 50ms in another. Every time time that poll occurs, Flash does something like this:

- Have (1000/framerate) miliseconds passed since the last frame update?

  - If no: do nothing and return
  - If yes: Execute a frame update:

    - Advance all (playing) timelines one frame
    - Dispatch all events (including an `ENTER_FRAME` event
    - Execute all frame scripts and event handlers with pending events
    - Draw screen updates
    - return

However, certain kinds of external events (such as keypresses, mouse events, and timer events) are handled asynchronously to the above process. So if you have an event handler that fires when a key is pressed, the code in that handler might be executed several times between frame updates. The screen will still only be redrawn once per frame update, unless you use the `updateAfterEvent()` method (global in AS2, attached to events in AS3).

Note that the asynchronous behavior of these events does not affect the timing of frame updates. Even if you use timer events to, for example, redraw the screen 50 times per second, frame animations will still occur at the published framerate, and scripted animations will not execute any faster if they're driven by the enterFrame event (rather than the timer).

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about using enter frame events, is your processing will degrade at the same pace as the rendering and you'll get a screen update right after the code block finishes.

Either method isn't guaranteed to occur at a specific time interval.  So your event handler should be determining how long it's been since it last executed, and making decisions off of that instead of purely how many times it's run.

Answer (score 0):

I think timerEvent and Enter Frame are both good options,  I have used both of them in my games. (  Did you mean timerEvent by timer loop? )

PS: notice that in slow machines the timer may not refresh quick enough, so you may need to adjust your code to make game work "faster" in slow machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a class such as TweenLite ( http://blog.greensock.com/tweenliteas3/ ) which is lightweight at about 3kb or if you need more power you can use TweenMax, which i believe is 11kb.  There are many advantages here.  First off, this "engine" has been thoroughly tested and benchmarked and is well known as one of the most resource friendly ways to animate few or even many things.  I have seen a benchmark, where in AS3, 1,500 sprites are being animated with TweenLite and it holds a strong 20 fps, as where competitors like Tweener would bog down to 9 fps http://blog.greensock.com/tweening-speed-test/.  The next advantage is the ease of use as I will demonstrate below.

```
//Make sure you have a class path pointed at a folder that contains the following.
import gs.TweenLite;
import gs.easing.*;

var ball_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var g:Graphics = ball_mc.graphics;
g.beginFill(0xFF0000,1);
g.drawCircle(0,0,10);
g.endFill();

//Now we animate ball_mc
//Example: TweenLite.to(displayObjectName, totalTweeningTime, {someProperty:someValue,anotherProperty:anotherValue,onComplete:aFunctionCalledWhenComplete});
TweenLite.to(ball_mc, 1,{x:400,alpha:0.5});
```

So this takes ball_mc and moves it to 400 from its current position on the x axis and during that same Tween it reduces or increases the alpha from its current value to 0.5.

After importing the needed class, it is really only 1 line of code to animate each object, which is really nice.  We can a also affect the ease, which I believe by default is Expo.easeOut(Strong easeOut).  If you wanted it to bounce or be elastic such effects are available just by adding a property to the object as follows.

```
TweenLite.to(ball_mc, 1,{x:400,alpha:0.5,ease:Bounce.easeOut});
TweenLite.to(ball_mc, 1,{x:400,alpha:0.5,ease:Elastic.easeOut});
```

The easing all comes from the gs.easing.* import which I believe is Penner's Easing Equations utilized through TweenLite.

In the end we have no polling (Open loops) to manage such as Timer and we have very readable code that can be amended or removed with ease.

It is also important to note that TweenLite and TweenMax offer far more than I have displayed here and it is safe to say that I use one of the two classes in every single project.  The animations are custom, they have functionality attached to them (onComplete: functionCall), and again, they are optimal and resource friendly.