# refering to a Movieclip insde a movieclip for a hittest

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have a key (as in for a door) movieclip called doorKey that's inside a movieclip called visuals.

Normaly when you put something on AS3 inside of the timeline and not inside a package you can do the following:

```
if (player.hitTestObject (visuals.doorKey))
```

How do I do this in a package?

research:
[Reference MovieClip After it is Added to Stage as a Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233462/reference-movieclip-after-it-is-added-to-stage-as-a-child)

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;


public class Test extends MovieClip
{
public var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
public var doorKey:Visuals = new Visuals();
public var visuals:Visuals; 

public function Test()
    {

        visuals.x = 25;
        visuals.y = 475;
        addChild(visuals)


        function loop(e:Event):void
        {
if (keyCollected == false)
        {
            //trace("player "+player);

            if (player.hitTestObject (doorKey))
            {
                doorKey.visible = false;
                keyCollected = true;
                trace("key collected");
            }
        }
```

Comment: top 1 bad practice - nested functions

Comment: Tried to write something to help you, but it all boils down to this... You need to learn the core concepts of classes, movieclips and how things are connected through the stage. Also, try to be more concise in what it is that you ask for and how things are connected. 

We have no idea what it is that creates "Test", when loop triggers and what it is that triggers it. We don't know what Visuals look like and why it is set to pos(25, 475). We also have no idea what player looks like, what scope it is in and what happens when you run the game, and what you expect to happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Flash Professional and Test is the document class of you FLA, and you have an instance of Visuals named visuals, and a instance named player and they're both on the stage then this code should work for you

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Test extends Sprite      //Document class
{
    public var visuals:Visuals;   //instance exists in FLA, doorKey is an instance on visuals
    public var player:Sprite      //instance exists in FLA

    public var keyCollected:Boolean = false;

    public function Test()  //Called when Test is created (when your swf loads since its the document class)
    {
        //To have a function loop every frame render
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void{
        if(player.hitTestObject(visuals.doorKey)){
            visuals.doorKey.visible = false;
            keyCollected = true;
            trace("key collected");
        }
    }
}
}
```

If these do not exist on the stage, then you will need to instantiate and add them in your constructor instead:

```
public function Test()
{
    visuals = new Visuals();
    player = new Sprite();
    addChild(visuals);
    addChild(player);
    //To have a function loop every frame render
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
}
```

When using a FLA in Adobe Flash, it automatically creates instances, adds them to the document objects display list (addChild), and sets the variables of your document class based on their names in the editor. The timeline code you showed above is taking advantage of the same functionality. In that example there is a player instance already on the stage, and the reference player is set to it. Same for visuals (which contains a property for doorKey). If those instances exist with those same names, then this line should still apply:

```
if (player.hitTestObject (visuals.doorKey))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the Test class a document class of your fla file, than player.hitTestObject (doorKey) will work. But in your code you have a method "loop" with event as param so you must have anything else that will trigger the event

Comment: i have difficulty grasping the concept of a workaround that will trigger the event. Could you please post a example of a diffrent trigger that also works.

Comment: i tried to understand what happens here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126385/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-implement-a-timer-loop-in-flex/127343#127343  but i failed to understand how to use it

Comment: Could i use TimerEvent.TIMER ? To create a sort of loop? Found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223663/having-difficulty-in-understanding-actionscript-3-timer-class